# How to display a string at a certain address with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I am dealing with a C dll where a function that returns a *pointer to a string*. I would like to print the content of this pointer.

Currently I have this:

```
>>> str_p = dll.myfunction(42)
>>> print str_p
1371678884
```

I tried `repr(str_p)`, `repr(str_p.value)`, but it seems `str_p` is seen as a integer.

Of course `print str(str_p)` will also print `1371678884`

Comment: `print str(str_p)` will print the same if `str_p` is seen as an integer.

Comment: So what you getting and what you expect to print?

Comment: The function returns a pointer to a string. Instead of a pointer I get the address (I suppose 1371678884 is an address). The question is how to fetch the data located at this address.

Comment: If you are using the ctypes module have you tried `ctypes.pointer(str_p)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the function's `restype` to [`ctypes.c_char_p`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p).

So this will work for you:

```
>>> dll.myfunction.restype = c_char_p
>>> str_p = dll.myfunction(42)
>>> print str_p
The Content Of Your String
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [ctypes.string_at](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.string_at):

> ***ctypes.string_at(address[, size])***
>
> This function returns the string
> starting at memory address address. If size is specified, it is used
> as size, otherwise the string is assumed to be zero-terminated.

Comment: No, this is absolutely wrong. The default restype is a `c_int`, so a 64-bit pointer will be truncated to 32-bit. The other answer is correct.

Comment: But it works perfectly and it answers my question :)

Comment: @nowox, without setting `restype` to a pointer type, your `str_p` variable is the address truncated to 32-bit. This only works if the string's address happens to fit in a 32-bit `int` or you happen to be using a 32-bit process. It will not work in general in a 64-bit process. You must set `restype` to a pointer type such as `c_char_p`.